# Sorting numbers closest to a given number

Tags: bash

If I want the closest numbers to 7 out of a range of 1-10, the expected outcome I would like is:

`7, 6, 8, 5, 9, 4, 10, 3, 2, 1`

I've looked around and can't really find an answer, is it even doable?

Pretty much trying to take an array with a series of numbers, and sorting them based on a target number with the closest at the top, and furthest towards the bottom.

Comment: What have you tried? Here's tips: `seq 10` to generate numbers - then for each number, use `awk` to output two columns: a absolute value of the difference of a number and the target number and a second column with the original number. So output lines like `6 1` `5 2` .. `0 7` `1 8` `2 9` with simple `awk '{print abs($1-7),$1}` script - then sort the numbers on the first field - `cut` the numbers - `paste` the numbers with a comma.

Comment: @KamilCuk That is the answer I was going to write. Please post it as one.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried some awk suggestion, but I guess part of my issue is not knowing how to put it in to the columns? I'm terrible with awk sorry.

Comment: Something like this would work if you were willing to use python: `vals=list(range(1,11));vals.sort(key=lambda x:(x-7)**2);print(vals)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the numbers on newlines
Compute the absolute value of the difference between target number and a number on each line
Sort using that computed value
Remove that computed value
Format output

```
seq 10 |
awk -vN=7 '{print abs($1-N),$1}  function abs(x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x; }' |
sort -n |
cut -d' ' -f2 |
paste -sd,
```

Comment: Note: on `macOS` `paste` should be `paste -sd, -`. It's real picky for whatever reason.

Comment: Is it possible to sort numbers with 2 columns of numbers in this manner too while taking in to account the 2nd number? I.e 7,7 8,7, 7,8 etc

Comment: @KamilCuk I can't seem to get that to work though. I have an array of numbers, formatted like "428,217" but I can't seem to make it factor in 217 at all as a separate number but output as being closest to a given one at the same time in a series of numbers if that makes sense? I think I'm in above my head

Comment: Then specify the field separator to a comma. Default separator is a whitespace.